# No view found for id when trying to go from fragment to fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I am using a Tabbar Layout to navigate between 3 fragments. (Home,Scanner and History)

Now in the "History" Fragment I have a button(called buttonChart), which should open a new fragment called "ChartFragment".

I tried using the transaction method, but it keeps giving me the error:

```
No view found for id 0x7f0900df (com.example.nlp_expense_tracker:id/historyFragment) for 
fragment ChartFragment{78bb9fe} (4658de1b-d3fe-4f12-98b7-735b882380f1 id=0x7f0900df)
```

Can anyone help me out?

Here is the History Fragment:

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val binding = FragmentHistoryBinding.bind(view)

    val exampleAdapter = ExampleAdapter()
    

    binding.apply{
        recyclerView.apply{

            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            adapter = exampleAdapter

        }                  

        buttonChart.apply {

            setOnClickListener {
                val fragment = ChartFragment()
                val transaction = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                transaction.replace(R.id.historyFragment, fragment)
                transaction.disallowAddToBackStack()
                transaction.commit()
            }
        }
    }
```

The ChartFragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ChartFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_chart) {

private val viewModel: PurchaseViewmodel by viewModels()
private lateinit var sparkView: SparkView


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chart, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    sparkView = view.findViewById(R.id.sparkView)
     val adapter = ReceiptsSparkAdapter(viewModel.receiptsChart)
    sparkView.adapter = adapter

}
}
```

And the MainActivity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager
private lateinit var tabs: TabLayout

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)
    tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs)
    setUpTabs()
}

private fun setUpTabs(){
    val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    adapter.addFragment(HomeFragment(),"")
    adapter.addFragment(Scanner(),"")
    adapter.addFragment(HistoryFragment(),"")
    viewPager.adapter = adapter
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
    tabs.getTabAt(0)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_home_24)
    tabs.getTabAt(2)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_show_chart_24)
    tabs.getTabAt(1)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_add_shopping_cart_24)
}

}
```

@addet the layout for activity and fragment

```
 Activity Layout:
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundcolor">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabInlineLabel="true"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/backgroundtab"
        app:tabIconTint="#c9d6df"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#c9d6df"
        />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<com.example.nlp_expense_tracker.ViewPagerCustom
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/viewPager"
android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the Fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragments.History.HistoryFragment">


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonChart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewEuro"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewEuro" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Recent Purchases"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Total amount spent:"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/totalSumTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="0.0"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewEuro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:text="€"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/totalSumTextView"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>


 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Where is `R.id.historyFragment` in layout?

Comment: what exacly do you mean? its the id of the fragment which has to be replaced as far as I understood how to use transactions.

Comment: Can you share the layout of the activity

Comment: sure, addet the xml from the activity and the fragment which includes the button that should open the new fragment. @Zain

Comment: Do you want to do fragment transaction within the ViewPager?

Comment: The viewPager is used for the Tabbar. So the fragment i want to go to on button click is not part of that tab Bar. I wouldn't mind if its a transaction within the viewPager tho if that makes it easier.

Comment: The fragment transaction should have a placeholder (typically a layout that hosts a fragment), I can't see this place holder in your shared code .. On the other has the transaction is handled automatically in the ViewPager using childFragmentManager whenever it's swiped or a page is selected without any intervention from developer side

Comment: How do i get this placeholder? Or get the transition to work? I'm sorry for these stupid questions, its my first time programming anything.

Comment: `transaction.replace(R.id.historyFragment, fragment)` this line means that you want to replace the current fragment that is hosted by the layout in main activity that has an id of `R.id.historyFragment` by `fragment`... So, you should have a layout viewgroup in main activity xml file that has an id of `R.id.historyFragment`

Comment: How can I create such a viewGroup in the xml?

Comment: @Kiwikid If you are ok showing your ChartFragment in a new screen, You better go for a new Activity.
1. Create a new activity with some plain layout e.g. FrameLayout and give some id to the FrameLayout.
2. Create a new fragment (ChartFragment) and add this fragment to the FrameLayout.
3. On button click, start this new activity and thats all.